# Django i18n not recognizing language files

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

On Django 1.4, I want to have two languages in my site, turkish('tr') and english('en').

This is my current setup:

settings.py:

```
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('tr', 'Turkish'),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # I have locale middleware
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',    
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/myproject/locale/', 
)
```

And I have my locale files as such directory order:

```
#tr files
/myproject/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
/myproject/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
#en files
/myproject/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
/myproject/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

And I still cannot see my translations, trying from my shell (it also doesn't work for templates as {% trans "Corporate" %}):

```
>>> from django.utils import translation
>>> translation.activate('tr')
>>> translation.ugettext('Corporate')
u'Corporate'
```

Am I missing anything here? Weirdly, it translates for words like 'Home' as original Django has translations for these but not my translation files.

Comment: Try without starting slash, .. or is that /home/username/myproject ..?

Answer (score 13):

In your case you must put into `LOCALE_PATHS` absolute path to your locale directory, i.e.

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/path_to_your_project/myproject/locale/', 
)
```

I guess you've tried to set relative path there.

I had similiar problem: i've been using django 1.3 and my locale directory was in the root of my project, i.e. near settings.py and manage.py files.
But when i create project with django 1.4, project directory structure have been changed: settings.py have moved into myproject/myproject folder. I still create `locale` folder in myproject/ (not in myproject/myproject). And with django 1.4 it is not working any more.

Reading [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) i understand, that django just can't find my `locale` folder. So solution that helps me - either move `locale` dir into myproject/myproject and don't set any `LOCALE_PATHS` OR leave `locale` dir in myproject/ path and add full path to it in settings.py in `LOCALE_PATHS` tuple.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. Had similar problems using Django 1.4.