# Django internationalization not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, localization, internationalization, django-i18n

My django is not executing translations that i define in my *.po files.

I have my setup like this:

> - MainFolder:
>
>   - locale
>
>     - en
>
>       - LC_MESSAGES
>
>         - django.po
>         - django.mo
>     - de
>
>       - LC_MESSAGES
>
>         - django.po
>         - django.mo
>   - app1
>
>     - settings.py
>   - app2
>   - ....

in my settings.py i have everything enabled i think:

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('de', _('German')),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ....
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

let's say my django.po file contains an example like this:

```
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Home22222"
```

and i use this in my template file:

```
{% trans "Home" %}
```

The home is not being replace by `Home22222`
It stays the same, even when i remove the LocaleMiddleware.

i did ran

```
makemessages --locale=en
```

and afterwards:

```
compilemessages
```

I am using `Python 2.7` and `django 1.6.4`

Comment: did you run `django-admin.py compilemessages` ?

Comment: Yes i did, i will add that to my original description, sorry.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/11609913/821594 can help

Comment: according to their documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations it is not necessary to set a locale path in my case, since i have it in a by default discoverable place i think

Comment: I tried setting the LOCALE_PATH, but the issue remains the same

Comment: First of all you define only one language in your LANGUAGES, secondly, could you please provide your urls? have you actually enabled i18n in your urls according to the documentation?

Comment: I have now defined 2 languages (see updated original post). I have also added the url for setting the language. I went to myurl/i18n/setlang which redirects me to the previous page. However the language is not changed.

Comment: After some more searching i followed this answer and everything worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031753/internationalization-doesnt-work-or-i-dont-know-how-to-make-it-work?rq=1 apparently i did set the incorrect locale path